# Saving JWT token to local storage

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I want to save a JWT token into local storage in order to authenticate routes. My code is below but when this route is hit the browser just sits on loading and then says this page isnt working. Removing the localStorage.setItem() makes it work. Im wondering why this is happening. Thanks.

```
} else {
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(Matched => {
          if (Matched) {
            //Create the payload for JWT to code
            const payload = { id: user.id, name: user.name, email: user.email };

            jwt.sign(
              payload,
              keys.JWT_KEY,
              { expiresIn: 3600 },
              (err, token) => {
                **localStorage.setItem("token", token);
                res.redirect("/");**
              }
            );
          } else {
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `localStorage.setItem("token", token)` doesn't exist in nodejs, so the app will crash on this line and `res.redirect("/");` is never executed, so the response is never sent back and your browser hangs while waiting for the response.

To fix it, send token back to client using `res.json({ token: token });` and run `localStorage.setItem("token", token);` in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the response, after sending back res.json({token: token}), how do I specify that localStorage.setItem is done in the browser. @John Lee

Comment: make sure you're using AJAX, and in the response section of that ajax request, use `localStorage.setItem`

Comment: Example 
`$.post('/login', { username: 'joe', password: '123'}, function(res){
    localStorage.setItem("token", res.token);
});`

Comment: is there a way to do this without using an ajax request?

Comment: Well you can use websocket or any other means of client-server communication. Ajax is the easiest you can get. The bottom line is the token generation must be done on server-side.